# c# Selenium WebDriver - How to disable notifications on Facebook Page?

Tags: c#, facebook, selenium, notifications, webdriver

I am a beginner in Selenium WebDriver, and I have a problem with poping out notification on Facebook page while I'm trying to log in. I searched a lot, but i did not find anyhing usefull. I found code in java, convert into C# but it didn't work.(I hope that a did it properly) I tried something like this, but nothing. Please, help with this if you can.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> hash = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            hash.Add("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
            ChromeOptions op = new ChromeOptions();
            op.AddAdditionalCapability("hash",hash);
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("path to googlewebdriver");

            driver.Url = "http://facebook.com";
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys("my email");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass")).SendKeys("mypassw" + Keys.Enter);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content_container']")).Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using any such automation to interact with the web UI is against Facebook’s terms to begin with … What are you actually trying to achieve here in the end?

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS 3.2_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use [**`Facebook Graph API`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) instead.

Comment: I want, that my program could easly handle browser level notification, accept or deny, and later click on something else.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want to disable "all" notification on chrome browser, you can use switch `--disable-notifications`

Code in C# to launch chrome with this switch:

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions"); // to disable extension
 options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications"); // to disable notification
 options.AddArguments("--disable-application-cache"); // to disable cache
 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Here's list of switches available for chrome browser: [Chromium Comamnd Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Alternatively, you have options to handle alert by using this code statement:

```
options.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Dismiss;
```

You have other options available here to accept, dismiss, ignore etc.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the annoying "`some-annoying-website` wants to:  Show notifications", set your `ChromeOptions` like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
```

And pass it to your `ChromeDriver`:

```
using (var chrome = new ChromeDriver(options)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromeOptions op = new ChromeOptions();  
op.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
```

Most importantly need to check the versions of Chrome Driver. Some versions it may not support.